# The concept of overfitting and underfitting

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

[image: Misclassification error vs training examples]

From my understanding, the model has high bias but low variance. This indicates underfitting. I  assume that the model can flawlessly match the training data since the error rate of misclassification stays zero as the train size grows up to around 124,000 samples. The sudden increase in misclassification error for the train set shows that as model complexity increases, the model tends to misclassify more because it is unable to capture the underlying pattern of data since it is a simplistic model. When it comes to the validation data, since this data is essentially a "never seen before" data, the validation error is initially quite high. The error for validation goes down   as the model gradually learns more.

Am I correctly interpreting the graph?

Comment: How would you expect the graph to look if the variance were high but the bias were low?

Comment: I think I would anticipate that the training curve would have a low error rate and the validation curve would have a greater error rate, with a sizable difference between the two curves, if the variance is high but the bias is low. The error rates of both curves should decline with increasing training size, but their separation might still be quite wide. Oh well, I think in this case, it looks more like an overfitting than an underfitting @Dave